# WCF Test Client error

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am running my WCF service with Entity Framework.

```
public List<Website> getWebsites()
{
        try
        {
            using (MyInfoEntities ent = new MyInfoEntities())
            {
                return ent.Websites.ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
}
```

But when I invoke my service using Visual Studio 2012 I get an error:

> Failed to invoke the service.
>   Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.

As I am totally new to WCF I don't know where to search and what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your probably not going to be able to return an entity framework object like that directly.  Complex objects that are returned from WCF need to be wrapped around a DataContract attribute such as the following:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Website
    {
        [DataMember]
        public long idWebsite{ get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Name{ get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string MacAddHostess { get; set; }
     }
```